# Is there a law that requires schools and doctors to provide records to a parent with legal custody

Tags: united-states

In the United States, I have joint legal custody of children but not physical. Children's mother has convinced school and family doctor to withhold all records. Is there a specific law that says schools and medical providers must communicate with parents?

Answer (score 2):

Even if there is a law, schools and medical providers may still refuse to give you the information. They may do that because they think the mother's reasons are more important, or because they don't know the laws, or because they don't think the laws apply in this case, or because they think it's safer for them legally to only give out this information if a court tells them to do so. The law may actually say that you may be able to get a court order if you have a good reason, and that's the only case where the school or medical provider has to give you the information, and the school or medical provider may know that.

Most likely you will need a lawyer to get this information.